# Geting the Label of Usb block device

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am unable to extract the usb name from a command to use it as variable.

```
sudo e2label /dev/sdb1 | grep -i /dev/
```

The result is:

```
/dev/sdb1 contains a vfat file system labelled 'ESD-USB'
```

What I tried:

```
sudo e2label /dev/sdb1 | grep -i /dev/ | sed -n "/'*'/p"
```

Produce the same result.

```
sudo e2label /dev/sdb1 | grep -i /dev/ | sed -n "/'*'/p"
```

If you see above the result I want to have is ESD-USB only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk`

```
sudo e2label /dev/sdb1 | awk -F\' '/\/dev\// {print $2}'
ESD-USB
```

Set field separator to single quote, search for `/dev/`, then print second field.

Comment: Using serve the purpose of producing the right output.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract what you want using *extended regular expressions* with `grep` using the `-E` option and the match-only `-o` option, e.g.

```
grep -E -o '\w+-\w+'
```

Where `\w` is shorthand for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and `'+'` for repetition means to match one-or-more times.

**Example use/Output**

```
$ echo "/dev/sdb1 contains a vfat file system labelled 'ESD-USB'" | 
  grep -E -o '\w+-\w+'
ESD-USB
```

Answer (score 1):

Use lsblk.

```
sudo lsblk -n -f /dev/sdb1 -o LABEL
```

Output:

```
ESD-USB
```

---

See: `man lsblk`

Comment: thanks a lot. This is the most reliable line of code to have in order to implement in my script.